# Get air ticket prices to show on website

Tags: ruby

How can I get all airline ticket prices? I want to show them on my website. Any free resource available? I already tried Skyscanner API, but that gives old deals.

Answer (score 0):

To get airline ticket prices, you'd need an **API or a web-page you can scrape from**.

Depending on what you want, you can make a list of websites you want to compile, such as American Airlines, United Airlines, etc, and scrape each one.

Google has an airline API where you can get the prices of flights. You can see it in action [here.](https://rapidapi.com/serg.osipchuk/api/GoogleFlightsAPI/functions) Unfortunately, (I assume it's the same thing as Google QPX Express), **it's being shut down April 10, 2018**.

Best bet is to use a web scraping library like **Nokogiri**.